# Code Igniter - the more I try to understand, the more I get confused

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I understand what MVC does. but not understand deep enough.

```
 <?php
class Orders_model extends CI_Model {

         function  __construct(){

                parent::__construct();
        }
        private $table_name='orders';

         public function get(){


                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('orders');
                $this->db->join('orders_content', 'orders.oid = orders_content.oid');
                $query = $this->db->get();


                $data=array();
                foreach($q->result_array() as $orders){
                $data[$orders['orders.oid']] = $orders['orders_content.oid'];
                }

                return $data;
        }


}

?>
```

the problem is that I have two tables: orders and orders_content. I am not sure if I can just join two tables and call the array to match if orders' oid and orders_content's oid is same and then show the data that are related.

In views/product_order.php

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="686">
          <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>

          </tr>
          <?php foreach($orders as $orders){?>
                  <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $orders->product_id;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $orders->title;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $orders->price;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $orders->quantity;?></td>

</tr>
          <?php  }?>

            </table>
```

I wonder how to display the orders on view which I have orders.php. because foreach $orders cant be from only orders table right? I am sorry but yes, I took a plunge into code igniter hoping to learn fast. Again MVC confuses me a little.

**EDIT**
One question: how to show the product_order.php to be viewable on browser?
I changed model code - does it look right?

**EDIT II**
1) I m looking to limit orders to only certain brand. So I am wondering if it is advisable to have manufacturer table join as well? For eg, manufacturer id = manfacturer name and then display orders of sold products only to certain brand.

2) Product_order.php is not viewable - I mean I tried ways to view the page to see if it works, but nothing comes up?

3) ok now, i edited the code according to Daimsy

```
    $data[$orders['orders.oid']] = $orders['orders_content.oid'];
```

This line is a error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
Why can't use object?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by @Raza Gill, you need to join the to tables (LEFT JOIN) like that

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->join('orders_content', 'orders.oid = orders_content.oid');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

In your model, you need than to collect the data to be passed to the view. You're not doing that right, cause you're making an assignemnt which has little sense (you're putting there a join clause?)

It should be like this:

```
$data =array();
foreach($q->result_array() as $orders)
{
   $data[] = $orders;
}

return $data;
```

**Following the MVC pattern**, you should now retrieve this array ($data) in your CONTROLLER, which handles then the passing to the right view.

So, in your controller, you should have something like this:

**Edited controller**:
Ok, based on your comment you want to call that product_order view. You cannot do that directly. Views are loaded (usually in controllers, but not mandatory) according to the URL, so if you want the page to be accessed at `index.php/product_order` you need to have a file called `product_order.php` in your controllers folder. If you don't specify the 2nd URI segment (like in your case), you need to use the default function `index()`. Your controller would look like this then:

```
class Product_order extends CI_Controller {

     function index()
     {
        $this->load->model('orders_model'); // (I'm assuming you're not autoloading it. Otherwise, just skip the loading of this model);
        $data['orders'] = $this->orders_model->get();
        $this->load->view('product_order',$data);
     }

}
```

In case you, in future, want to add a method, say to view a specific product, you can do `index.php/product_order/view_product/20' for example, so you'll have:

- product_order : --> the controller (product_order.php)
- view_product : --> the method inside the controller AND
- 20 : --> the ID of your selected product, that has to be passed to the method above. Like `function view_product($id) { /....}`.
  Hope MVC is getting clearer for you.

**//End edit;**

You can **now, in your view** 'product_order.php', collect the array (in CI, the indexes of the array provided to the view are transformed in the omonimous variable) with a foreach, like you're doing. But beware, you're calling them as if were objects, while instead you provided an associative array. SO it should be like this:

```
 <?php foreach($orders as $order) : ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $order['product_id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $order['title'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $order['price'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $order['quantity'];?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You're code would have been fine if you'd used $q->result() instead of $q->result_array()

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, wow thank you for detailed explaination. it is making sense to me.. so we don't have to declare the two tables as private? how did it get the data from two joined tables? it is my question

Comment: @Josephine why would you want that? just pass the name of the table to the Active Record and its fine, no need to create object vars or whatever. How CI gets the data it pertains to its internal working, so far you should no worry about that...Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: @Josephine That's the whole point of using a framework. It's using ActiveRecords (a whole class dedicated to do database operations so you won't have to). http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, ok i followed your instructions, but my question is how to view the page? it is in views folder. i mean if i go to https://domain.com/partners/index.php/product_order -- it doesnt work?

Comment: @Josephine You cannot call a view directly! You need to call the controller (which is the first URI segment), using the `index()` method if leaving the 2nd URI segment blank. See my updated answer ('Edited controller' part)

Comment: @Damien Prisy, yes, i got it working to be viewable. But as you can see above that i edited on error. Also I have another error: Undefined variable: data. Does it mean I have to define data?

Comment: @Josephine I don't know why are you still doing this `$data[$orders['orders.oid']] = $orders['orders_content.oid'];` We already showed you how you have to pass that part, first from the model to the controller, then to the view, please follow the suggestions. Refer to codeigniter user guide also when in doubt also, it's pretty clear on every aspect!

Comment: @Damien, I have read user guide - the problem is tat other files also use $data, so I think I have to be consistent no? and also sorry if you are mad or something. thank you for all your time and help

Comment: No, I'm not mad, lol, don't worry. $data is just a common name to refer to..a data, and as it is enclosed inside functions its fine to always use that for consistency. You CAN use $data, but not how you're doing, because - as you see, you get errors...I provided you with a suggestion on how to use $data correctly to get you query results, pass those from the model to the controller, pass it from the controller to the view, and how to display those to the view, all followed by an explanation. If it's not clear, we're here to help. But you should follow suggestions when you ask for them! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your view has a subtle mistake: You have:

```
<?php foreach($orders as $orders){?> <!-- nb. both variables are plural -->
```

which should be:

```
<?php foreach($prders as $order){?> <!-- nb. second variable is singular -->
```

Similarly:

```
<td><?php echo $orders->product_id;?></td>
```

will now have to be:

```
<td><?php echo $order->product_id;?></td>
```

What you had before was overwriting the `$orders` array the first time around the loop so it wouldn't function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join the two tables and get the result as one set. Try to do this in your model class:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->join('orders_content', 'orders.oid = orders_content.oid');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer.. but don't we need to declare two tables as private?

Comment: No, in codeigniter it can pick up that from the database.php file in config folder (I am assuming you have configured that)

Comment: no i havent configured it. From what i see, we have to declare private somewhere. I will figure it out. thank you for your help.